# How to boot into single user mode in 14.04

Tags: boot, kernel

I am trying to switch to single user mode in 14.04. I tried

> sudo telinit 1

but this never gives you a prompt.

I then tried editing the boot options from the grub menu when I reboot. I see a line that ends

```
ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

but if you add the word single in there you never get a prompt.

This problem appears to be reproducible by others.

How do you get into single user mode?

Comment: @user68186 The problem is that seems outdated now as the answer doesn't work in 14.04.

Comment: Try changing virtual consoles, ctrl-alt-F2 for example. If that fails, please identify your graphics card.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Do you mean change virtual console after doing "sudo telinit 1"? I am not ever sure ubuntu has runlevels does it?

Comment: Not really as Ubuntu uses upstart at the moment and the run levels have all been the same for a while now. Boot using the "single" option, then change virtual consoles.

Comment: To a large extent, "runlevels" are depreciated with both upstart and systemd. Ubuntu is moving to systemd, see  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd "systemd has the concept of targets which is a more flexible replacement for runlevels in sysvinit." I respectfully suggest you at least take a look at systemd ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Can I ask, does adding "single" to the line in the question work for you? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I do not use Ubuntu 14.04. If it is not working, you probably will need to file a bug report and use a live USB to make changes / repairs. What are you trying to do that you can not use `sudo -i` from a graphical desktop?